# facebook open graph object

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I am getting the following error all the time, any idea?

```
has og:type of 'website'. The property 'article' requires an object of og:type 'article'."}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea.  You have an og:article meta tag in the HTML being sent to Facebook's linter.

Put your URL into:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint and check it out.